# Levitical Law obsolete?

Tags: mosaic-law, christian-living, grace, law-and-gospel

Paul says [Romans 6:14-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%206&version=KJV)

> 14 For sin shall not have dominion over you: for ye are not under the law, but under grace.
>
> 15 What then? shall we sin, because we are not under the law, but under grace? God forbid.

Does that mean that we no longer need to follow the Laws given in the Old Testament, such as

- not eating pork
- circumcision
- grace at each meal
- not to reap the entire field
- Not to intermarry with gentiles
- etc.

Is there a specific scripture that abolishes these laws and gives us a different set?

I assume that they refer to the Resurrection as the event that pulled us from under the law. but it seems unclear to me as to whether or not we should still obey these laws.

Can I eat bacon?

Comment: Seems like a dupe of one of these: [Do we have to obey the laws of the bible? If so, what laws?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15) | [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/456) It's also too broad a topic in my opinion. There's many opinions on the extent to which the Law is still applicable and a number of various reasonings for those opinions.

Comment: That's off-topic too: [What to do with "Is x a sin" questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1486)

Comment: From a Seventh Day Adventist perspective, no. The laws in Leviticus is not obsolete.

Comment: Yes, you can have bacon *after* you read Acts 10.

Comment: Related: [What is the old covenant of Hebrews 8:6](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14002/3889)